# How to use dynamically created object in MEF?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, mef

Assume I have a class `Cookie`:

```
class Cookie
{
   List<Ingredient> ingredients;

   public Cookie(List<Ingredient> ingredients)
   {
      this.ingredients = ingredients;     
   }
}
```

`Cookie` is used in `CookieMonster` class, which uses MEF:

```
[Export]
class CookieMonster: ICookieMonster
{
   [Import]
   ICookie cookie;
}
```

This code obviously will not work, because `Cookie` doesn't have `[Export]` attribute. The problem is that instance of Cookie is created in runtime and we need that exact instance.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

If you add a `CompositionBatch` to your MEF initialization, and add an instance of the `Cookie` object to this batch (either through `new` or use an existing instance), then you can import your `Cookie` object where you need to use it.

```
var container = new CompositionContainer(aggregateCatalog);
var batch = new CompositionBatch();
batch.AddExportedValue<ICookie>(new Cookie());

container.Compose(batch);
```

In this case you will then be able to do `[Import] Cookie myCookie;` in the classes that are created by MEF.

Currently your `Cookie` object does not implement ICookie (nor export it, as you correctly said), so importing `ICookie` will not give you anything.